# How do I upload multiple files in parallel through FTP using QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I have written a test class that I'm using to learn more about `QNetworkAccessManager` and its functionality related to FTP uploading. I'm trying to upload files from my Raspberry Pi to my Windows PC through FTP and this works well when I just want to upload a single file. However, I want to transmit multiple files at once; the same way FileZilla does this when you drag a folder between client and host; it starts multiple up/downloads instead of one after the other sequentially. Below are my `ftp_test.h`  and `ftp_test.cpp` files. If I provide `upload()` with a list of filenames, it will for each name in this list, do a put request on the server. However, only the first file gets uploaded, the second, third, fourth. etc. get ignored.

```
class ftp_test: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ftp_test    (QObject *p = 0): QObject(p) { }
    void upload(QString video_directory, std::vector<QString> filename);

public slots:
    void uploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal);
    void uploadDone();

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
    QFile *data;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QEventLoop loop;
};
```

And my `ftp_test.cpp`

```
void ftp_test::upload(QString video_directory, std::vector<QString> filename)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < filename.size(); i++)
        {
            QUrl url("ftp://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx/" + filename[i]);
            url.setUserName("pi");

            if(QFile::exists(video_directory + filename[i]))
            {
                data = new QFile(video_directory + filename[i], this);
                if (data->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
                {
                    reply = nam.put(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
                    connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
                    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(uploadDone()));
                    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), SLOT(someError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Oops";
                return;
            }
        }
        loop.exec();
}

void ftp_test::uploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug() << "Uploaded" << bytesSent << "of" << bytesTotal;
}

void ftp_test::uploadDone()
{
    qDebug() << "Finished" << reply->error();
    data->deleteLater();
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = 0;
    loop.quit();
}
```

I thought about making multiple threads for this to work, but before I delve into that, maybe there is something I'm missing.

I'm aware that it will stop uploading after the first upload was succesful, but it doesn't matter because I'm still not seeing parallel uploads.

Is this the way it's supposed to work? How do I achieve concurrent transfer of files instead of sequential?

Comment: I would expect that it uploads files in parallel. Note that you overwrite `data` and `reply` in each iteration, which will result in a memory leak. Have you checked if some if test are failing? How did you checked for simultaneous uploads? Using [`QObject::sender`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) in `uploadProgress` may be helpful.

Comment: Good ideas; I want to overwrite `data` because I will need a new file to upload! None of the ifs are failing and it breaks twice (as expected) on the `put()` method, so I would expect it to send it in parallel. I checked for simultaneous uploads by looking at my other PC, the FTP server, and looking at the log during and after transmission; it clearly showed it sent them one after the other.

Comment: Based on [this post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26802858/Multiple-simultaneous-requests-with-QNetworkAccessManager.html) it may be useful to create multiple `QNetworkAccessManager`s. `QNetworkAccessManager` is able to send multiple requests in parallel, but doesn't mention clearly how much it effectively uses in each situation (6 requests for HTTP on desktop).

Comment: @m7913d Indeed, that's the biggest confusion in the documentation; I don't think it's sending them in parallel for FTP. Gonna try that and report back with how it works.

Comment: That is really strange, it should work based on [this post](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/18288)

Comment: @m7913d I have tried it again and it worked. You have to create separate `QObjects` along with the network managers, I just created a second networkmanager inside the same ftp_test object, which didn't work. Making two ftp_test objects, `t1` and `t2`, I achieved concurrency. I'll make a detailed answer to my question later! Thanks for the pointer to that post as it was the key!